# I need to re-develop this recursive function

Tags: php

i have a table with resellers and a 'parentId' field if a reseller is a reseller of another.. If a reseller logins to the web app i want to show all his/her clients and all the clients of his/her resellers etc.

i write this recursive function but it takes too long to fetch the clients because if you have in total 60 resellers will execute 60 times..

Any idea how to write this in better way or any other idea?

```
function showClients($resellerId){
    $strCurrentUser = $con->query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE resellerId='$resellerId'");
    if($strCurrentUser->rowCount()>0){
        while($CRow = $strCurrentUser->fetch()){
            echo "<tr>
                <td>...fetching data</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }
    $strReseller = $con->query("SELECT * FROM resellers WHERE parentId='$resellerId'");
    if($strReseller->rowCount()>0){
        while($RRow = $strReseller->fetch()){
            showClients($RRow['Id']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Write a single query for this as `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE resellerId IN (SELECT Id FROM resellers WHERE parentId='$resellerId')`

Comment: And what about the clients of the reseller of the reseller?